# $('.item_name:containes("text")') causing IE8 to freeze on page load

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, loops, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-8

I have a loop on $(document).ready to check though a an array of text which calls a function to search for each snippet of text within an element and use that as a selector.

This code works 100% in FF, Chrome, IE9+ etc.. but freezes up the browser in IE8.

```
var setText = function(value)
{
    if(typeof $('.item_name:contains("'+value+'")') != 'undefined'){
      // Do something, it still freezes with nothing set here.
    }
}

// In the real script there maybe upwards of 20 items in this array.
var item_list = new Array('a','b','c');

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $.each(item_list, function(index, value) {
       setText(value); 
    });
});
```

I've disabled the setText function and it works fine, so its not the loop, it seems to be the :contains selector.

Why is this happening? How else can I do this? I cant edit the HTML code itself.

The idea is I have to change parts of the HTML markup with jQuery, add some HTML and change some CSS values, but the only unique Identifier I have is the text within '.item_name'.

The page in question which freezes that this is run on contains at most 3 separate instances of '.item_name'. Any of which may be targeted depending on the searches string.

I am using jQuery 1.7.1, can not update this.

```
if($('.item_name:contains("'+value+'")').length > 0){ // Also causes it to freeze.
```

Comment: `$('.item_name:contains("'+value+'")')` returns a jQuery object which is not `undefined`. You should use `length` property instead.

Comment: wrt the last line, did you mean `$('.item_name:contains("'+value+'")').length > 0`?

Comment: @undefined, see the last line, using length also causes a freeze, regardless of what is proper that doesn't fix it.

Comment: @Ezra You haven't used `length` property! `if($('.item_name:contains("'+value+'")').length > 0){`

Comment: @undefined, woops.. correct. but still does not effect the freeze. Will  update date on my question.

Comment: how many `.item_name` is present in the page? Also can you share a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @ArunPJohny, on the page it freezes on there should be at most 3. See it here: http://www.no1fitness.co.nz/treadmills/freerun-treadmill-02518?nav=5726

However the item of text it loops though maybe upto 30.

Comment: It seems to be working here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/umTdG/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny, that looks about right. Strange indeed.

I've added the offending code page into the live website, at http://www.no1fitness.co.nz/treadmills/freerun-treadmill-02518?nav=5726, you can find it on line 137 of the source code. Open that in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a selector performance problem.

I would suggest the following steps 
1. Add a id like `id="crazy-products"` the the container which contains all the `item_name` elements
2. Change `$('.item_name:contains("'+value+'")')` to $('.item_name:contains("'+value+'")', $('#crazy-products'))

IE8 or below does not have the `document.getElementsByClassName` implementation so it is looking all the elements in the document to see whether the given filter condition is applied to it. If we can pass an context to the filter condition we can narrow the scope of the document lookup thus improving the performance of the page.

For better understanding of the problem you can look at jquery.js line number 4215 (`found = filter( item, match, i, curLoop )`) and look at the size of the array `curLoop`, it looks to be enormously large in your case, by passing a id based context to the filter can can reduce it.

Comment: that would be nice, but I cant add an id. (unless u mean by JavaScript), I cant modify the HTML directly at all.

Comment: Can you try `var context = $('#page_content > .main_content_holder > .main > .cross_sell > .products');

$('.item_name:contains("'+value+'")', context)`

Comment: hmm, thats improved the load quite a lot, still an 8 second freeze while loading.. but it dosnt crash the browser anymore. However that context changes throughout the site. It will need to be active on different pages with different div layouts.

Comment: an `id` selector will be the optimal solution, if you can't have it I think is the best you can get. Otherwise need to do further analysis on improving the selector further. also let me know if you have any other ideas. It is purely a problem with using a optimal selector

Comment: :/ yeah.. sadly I don't have control over that code. I can only add JavaScript.

Comment: But if you can convince the html author to add an `id` it can improve the performance a lot, it will worth the time spent convince them

Comment: I cant, its a set platform and a separate company running it. It will cost us several thousand to add something like that. :(

Comment: ok, `$('.item_name:contains("'+value+'")')` without any context takes more than 150 milliseconds, with the above context takes only 10 milliseconds but using an id context brings it down to 4-5 milliseconds

Comment: Also, let me know what solution you are going with

Comment: yeah it'll be some kinda of system with the context. I don't know how yet though, that'll be a Monday job.

Comment: anyway let me know the solution, spent quite some time to find out the problem